# Xcode wont suggest or autocomplete or connect

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hi from this morning i've got a weird thing !

Xcode won't `Suggest` ,

won't `AutoComplete` ,

won't give `color to my codes` ,

wont give me any `Errors` and won't `find out` my properties or methods or anything !

But indexing compelete with success

Build compelete with success

Run compelete with success

[image]

Comment: go to Xcode preferences, click location, click on derived data and delete the folder, quit Xcode and restart that should do the job

Comment: remove `Derived Data` or click on `ctlr + shift  + k` or  `ctlr + alt + shift  + k `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Had same problem , and i have solutions for that :

## 1.DerivedData :

Xcode caches some files that cause this problem

Go to --> `YourUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/`

Then remove the `DerivedData` directory in the `Xcode` directory

if you didnt saw Library folder because it is a hidden directory

[Here is a good Resource of how to show hidden files in macOS](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/show-hidden-files-mac-3520878/)

## 2.Memory

clean up some memory , on devices that have 
8GB of `RAM` this problem Occurred more

I suggest you to use `CleanMyMac3` it also free a lot of `Storage`

[You can download it from here](https://macpaw.com/cleanmymac)

## 3.Code Clean !

I suggest you to code clean first !

a few things that i used to do in my Projects :

1. For every method that only belongs to body of that class use `fileprivate` which means this method is available for the class and extenstions which just `private` is only available to the body of the class
2. Any property that belongs only to body of the class should mark with `fileprivate`
3. Avoid of declaring variables outside of the class ! this will get memory all the time
4. `Deinit()` the `Models` after you end up working with them
5. Avoid of doing `Notification Center` because you forget to dispose them ! instead of that i suggest you to start `RxSwift` that works better you can find it here

[RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift)

## 4. Code Completion

go to the Xcode->Preferences->TextEditing

Check that is your code completion options is checked to true

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Restart your Xcode.
If still not work, restart your computer.

Comment: i've been restarted my macbook even ! :D , restarted xcode and nothing happens :/